# Não estou a conseguir guardar dados no ficheiro ele cria o ficheiro mas so que não armazena nada

Tags: c

```
void Criar_Ficheiro_Pizza()
{
    FILE *B;
    if ((B = fopen("Pizzas.txt", "a")) == NULL)
    printf("\n\t !!! Ficheiro nao pode ser guardado!!!");
    else
    {
        pizzas *aux;
        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            fprintf(B,"%d\t %c\t %.2f\t\n", aux->codpizza, aux->descricao, aux->preco);
            aux=aux->prox;
        }
        fclose(B);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O ponteiro para aux foi criado mas não inicializado, contendo qualquer valor ao iniciar o loop. É provável que seu programa está fechando ao tentar acessar o ponteiro, interrompendo por falha de segmentação.
Você deve carregar os dados a serem gravados no ponteiro aux antes de iniciar a gravação.

Para carregar os dados em aux, você precisa de chamar alguma função que retorna esses dados como por exemplo:

```
pizzas *aux = getPizzas();
```

Provavelmente esse programa já possui esses dados. Assim o correto seria receber os dados como um parâmetro da função:

```
void Criar_Ficheiro_Pizza(pizzas *aux)
```

Procure no programa pelo texto "pizzas" pois assim você conseguirá localizar pontos em que esses dados são gerados.

Comment: como fazer isso é que estou ainda a aprender a programação...

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta, adicionando uma explicação sobre onde conseguir os dados. Se possível adicione o código completo para facilitar a explicação.